# Find maximum free block of time

Tags: python

I have a question. Say I was given a list of tuples with the a start time and finish time of minutes watched on a video. (ex. [(0,10),(17,25)] ) sorted by the start time. I am given the total length of the video (ex. 30) and asked to find the maximum total minutes of an uninterrupted period of unwatched minutes. So in this instance, the answer would be 7 minutes. (From 10 to 17).

Here is my solution:

```
#example data
video = [(5,10),(13,18),(15,23),(21,23)]
total_minutes_video = 30

#first row calculate free_minutes from start
free_minutes= video [0][0]
lastend = video [0][1]

for beg,end in video :
  if beg>lastend:
    free_minutes = max(beg-lastend,free_minutes)
  lastend = max(lastend,end)

#last row, have to check how many minutes until end of video
free_minutes= max(free_minutes,total_minutes_video-video[len(video)-1][1])

print(free_minutes)
```

Obviously its not the prettiest, I feel like I could do better. Any ideas to avoid having to do the logic at the top and bottom?

Comment: You could simply add (-1,0) and (total_minutes_video, total_minutes_video+1) at the beginning and end of your list.

Comment: @Julien Hm not bad, is the logic in the middle pretty good then?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your list into a list of unwatched intervals:

```
v = [(0, 0)] + video + [(total_minutes_video, total_minutes_video)]
unwatched = [(a[1], b[0]) for a, b in zip(v[:-1], v[1:])]
```

Then find the longest:

```
worst = max(unwatched, key=lambda x: x[1] - x[0])
```

---

If you're concerned about memory, you can do this purely with generators:

```
import itertools
v = itertools.chain([(0, 0)], video, [(total_minutes_video, total_minutes_video)])
unwatched = ((a[1], b[0]) for a, b in zip(v[:-1], v[1:]))
worst = max(unwatched, key=lambda x: x[1] - x[0])
```

Comment: Wow, python can't do tuple unpacking in lambdas... WTF.

Comment: Very clever, I was hoping I could do this without creating an ancillary array but the code is definitely cleaner than mine, thanks

Comment: You can certainly do this with generators and `itertools.chain` if you don't want it to take up any memory. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to skip logic you could *enumerate* and shorten the range by 1 and then take the differences of the 1 position of current item and 0 position of the next item, of course we would have to take the inverse of this using `*-1` and append those values to a list, I tried just doing the list in reverse to skip that but I couldn't. Then we could we could grab the difference between our last value 1 position and total time, append that. And just take the max of that list.

```
free = [(item[1] - v[idx+1][0])*-1 for idx, item in enumerate(v[:-1])]
free.append(total - v[-1][1])
print(max(free))
```

> ```
> 7
> ```

if it must be one line, although violates PEP-8 line max

```
free = max([(item[1] - v[idx+1][0])*-1 for idx, item in enumerate(v[:-1])] + [total -v[-1][1]])
```

Comment: This is also clever, similar to the one above but saves some space. I would rather not have to run that last line but it looks like this might be unavoidable. Thank you

Comment: @TimothyChang  we can make it one line if you must :)